# Javascript glow/pulsate effect to stop on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, glow

I have the following Javascript to make a text link glow/pulsate continuously.  This link reveals another section of the same page so I would like it to stop once the user has clicked on it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function pulsate() {
          $(".pulsate").animate({opacity: 0.2}, 1200, 'linear')
                       .animate({opacity: 1}, 1200, 'linear', pulsate);
        }

        pulsate();
     }); 
    </script>
```

So basically, I just need to know what I need to add here so that the effect stops once it has been clicked.

If the same link is clicked again, the revealed section of the page will hide - is it too much trouble to make the effect start again after a second click?

I look forward to an answer from you good people.

Scott.

Comment: This seems perilously close to recreating the <blink> tag.  If the action is that important, you should probably just make it simple to do, cut out other, less important choices, or just do it in the background in advance...

Comment: kind of like <blink> yes but with a fade - don't worry it doesn't look quite as cheesy on the page in a subtle font colour.  I just need it to stop once it has been clicked on.

Comment: Heh, as long as you're using it with purpose and moderation, then.  :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply bind to the click event and call [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). You should also ensure that the opacity has been restored to **1**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function pulsate() {
        $(".pulsate").animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 1200, 'linear')
                     .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1200, 'linear', pulsate)
                     .click(function() {
                         //Restore opacity to 1
                         $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1200, 'linear');
                         //Stop all animations
                         $(this).stop();
                     });
        }

    pulsate();
});
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/EfjT5/).

Comment: I am not feeling very comfortable with that approach. For every loop the `$('.pulsate')` DOM elements are registering a click function. And if have let say 5 elements and they loop for around one minute there will be around less than (5*60) function to stop it.

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan When the pulsate function is called by the animation, you could have it be called with a parameter that tells it not to register the click handler.

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan, if you have a better answer, post it. Please don't completely change my answer (or anyone else's) and add an "edit by" line.

Comment: Got that right ;). I do not have the better answer then Hill's, I think it suits the best.

Comment: @James Hill why does your fourth parameter on the animate function calls "pulsate" without especifying its a method? can it pass arguments?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is pretty simple. Have your `pulsate()` function make sure that `.pulsate` doesn't have the class `stop` before doing its thing. If it does have that class, then the `pulsate()` function will simply animate the link back to full opacity, but not continue the pulsating.

James' example works as well, but I prefer my approach because his way binds the `click` event to `.pulsate` over and over again. This kind of thing may cause problems depending on what the rest of your page is doing.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/2f9ZU/

```
function pulsate() {
    var pulser = $(".pulsate");
    if(!pulser.hasClass('stop')){
        pulser.animate({opacity: 0.2}, 1200, 'linear')
        .animate({opacity: 1}, 1200, 'linear', pulsate);
    }else{
        pulser.animate({opacity:1},1200)
            .removeClass('stop');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    pulsate();
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('.pulsate').addClass('stop');
    });
});
```